# Change calculator program java (looping)

Tags: java, loops, calculator

Write a program that repeatedly reads an integer between 0 and
100 that represents a number of cents. Convert that number of
cents to the equivalent number of quarters, dimes, nickels, and
pennies. The program should output the maximum number of
quarters that will fit, then the maximum number of dimes that will fit
into what is left, and so on. Then the program will ask for the next
amount. If the amount is negative, the program should quit.

This is what i have so far, im not sure how to make it loop or count the number or each coin.

```
System.out.println("Enter number of cents (Negative value to quit):");
int cents;
cents = scan.nextInt();

while (cents > 0 )
{
    if (cents >= 25)
    {
        System.out.println("Quarter");
        cents -= 25;
    }
    else if ( cents >= 10 )
    {
        System.out.println("Dime");
        cents -= 10;
    }
    else if (cents >= 5 )
    {
        System.out.println("Nickle");
        cents -= 5 ;
    }
    else if (cents >= 1 )
    {
        System.out.println("Penny");
        cents -= 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also use `%` (modulo) for the calculation. That way you could solve the task without looping at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can decompose the problem in 2 parts :

- `do` ask an amount `while` the amount is non negative
- Decompose the given amount with integer division

1) Ask an input in the main method

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int input;
do {
  input = scan.nextInt();
  decompose(input);
} while (input > 0);
```

2) Write the decomposition in another method :

```
public static void decompose(int cents) {
  if(cents >= 25) {
    int quot = cents / 25;
    System.out.println(quot + " Quarter");
    cents -= quot * 25;
  }

  if(cents >= 10) {
    int quot = cents / 10;
    System.out.println(quot + " Dime");
    cents -= quot * 10;
  }

  [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well my suggestion is to use a HashMap. Where your code can look something like that:

```
System.out.println("Enter number of cents (Negative value to quit):");
Map<String, Long> countMap = HashMap<String, Long>();
countMap.put("Quarter", 0);
countMap.put("Dime", 0);
countMap.put("Nickle", 0);
countMap.put("Penny", 0);

   int cents;
   cents = scan.nextInt();

   while (cents > 0 )
   {
       if (cents >= 25)
       {
           System.out.println("Quarter");
           countMap.put("Quarter", countMap.get("Quarter")+1L);
           cents -= 25;
        }
        else if ( cents >= 10 )
        {
            System.out.println("Dime");
            countMap.put("Dime", countMap.get("Dime")+1L);
            cents -= 10;
        }
        else if (cents >= 5 )
        {
            System.out.println("Nickle");
            countMap.put("Nickle", countMap.get("Nickle")+1L);
            cents -= 5 ;
        }
        else if (cents >= 1 )
        {
            System.out.println("Penny");
            countMap.put("Penny", countMap.get("Penny")+1L);
            cents -= 1;
        }
}
```

Now you have all you need.

```
System.out.println("Quarter: " + countMap.get("Penny"));
System.out.println("Dime: " + countMap.get("Dime"));
System.out.println("Nickle: " + countMap.get("Nickle"));
System.out.println("Penny: " + countMap.get("Penny"));
```

Comment: Why not just use 4 `int` variables? Way easier than a hash map.